# How to make the coordinates of cell variable even if it is in quotes?

Tags: excel, d3.js, vba

The formula im using is `=INDIRECT($A$1&"!D1")`, which is just giving me data from a sheet whose name is is `A1`!. However, I don't just want whats in `D1`, i want `D2,D3,D4`..etc. But when i drag the box down, it the number after the `D` stays constant. Is there a way i can make it variable? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=INDIRECT($A$1&"!D" & ROWS($1:1))
```

Then copy down.